# Use an Angular Service in an Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I have a service and I have a http interceptor. I would like to notify my service everytime a intercept happens. This is my code:

interceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MastermindService } from './mastermind.service';

@Injectable()
export class LogInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private mastermindService: MastermindService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.mastermindService.notify(`${request.method} ${request.urlWithParams} ${JSON.stringify(request.body)} ${request.responseType}`)
    return next.handle(request);

  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MastermindService {
  private subject = new Subject<string>();

  public notify(message: string): void {
    this.subject.next(message);
  }
  public listen(): Observable<string> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { GameboardItemComponent } from './shared/gameboard-item/gameboard-item.component';
import { LogInterceptor } from './core/log.interceptor';
import { MastermindService } from './core/mastermind.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
   
  ],
  providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LogInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [MastermindService]}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [GameboardItemComponent] // define the dynamic component here in module.ts

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Further more I have a log component where the intercept messages should be outputed:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MastermindService } from 'src/app/core/mastermind.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-log',
  templateUrl: './custom-log.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-log.component.scss']
})
export class CustomLogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private mastermindService: MastermindService) { }
  logs: string[] = [];
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mastermindService.listen().subscribe((event) => {
       this.logs.push(event);
       console.log(event);
    });
  }


}
```

The problem is that there is not output on the console. And there is also no element in my logs array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making any requests  in CustomLogComponent component? If you want to store requests made before you load CustomLogComponent you need to swap your subject with BehaviourSubject with inital value of null or ReplaySubject with buffer size 1